Ashvamedha Yajna Misunderstood
In many cases, the more controversial practices of the Ashvamedha Yajna aren't seen in other texts like Mahabharata and Ramayana. Also, in many cases in Satapatha Brahmana the animal is allegorical to a statue made of rice and barley or some other object. Can someone give an actual and proper account of this ritual I think all of the content isn't being taken in and I am confused in general.

The controversial part of Aswamedha is seen in both Mahabharata  and Ramayana but not in other parts of the same book. In Mahabharata when a king does it, it does involve the controversial part. But when Krishna and Yudhisthira do it, it doesn't. Similarly, in Bala Kanda when Dasaratha does it, it has the controversial part, but when Rama does it in Uttara Kanda, it doesn't.

@SuradoeUchiha interesting

The Hindu religion has changed a lot since the composition of the earliest Vedas. What we consider now to be "controversial", was not so in ancient times. We are talking several thousand years ago; you cannot apply our sentiments to society in those times. What our Punjabi ancestors were doing 5000 or whatever years ago is different to what we are doing today.
In Vedic India, the emphasis was on performance of Vedic rituals to please deities for rewards. The Ashwamedha yajna was one such ritual. It is a fertility ritual, and as such, it has "controversial" acts like the mock-sex act between the chief queen and the horse. It is symbolic. The holy Ashva in the yajna was consecrated with mantras to imbue it with virility, so when the queen does the mock-sex act, she and the kingdom get imbued with virility and power. That is the symbolism.

I don't believe it was mock --- even if it may be viewed as such it seems more procedural. But, my question is whether the procedure is actually being defined correctly or are their other ways of interpretation?

@Haridasa I meant mock as in real sex doesn't happen, just the genitals come into contact. And this is the procedure, I'm not aware of other interpretations. The instructions for the procedure are clear.
